# Using Gstreamer in Windows

Tags: windows, installation, video-streaming, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I usually use Gstreamer in Linux and there I install it simply using the command

```
yum install gstreamer...
```

and then I can play an RTP stream by the command `gst-launch-0.01 playbin2 ...`
Now I need to do the same in Windows and I tried to download the installation application from this [website](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.2.1/) and then  I opened the command line and type the following command:

```
gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! autoaudiosink
```

and got this error:

```
'gst-launch-0.10' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I know I am missing something like linking or something, but I don't know how to do it!

Do anyone have a good HOWTO step by step on how to install and try gstreamer in Windows?

Comment: FWIW, this is the document for Installing GStreamer on Windows: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, make sure your path variable points to where you installed gstreamer.

Secondly, you seem to have installed gsteamer-1.0, which is independent of 0.10.

Try running gst-launch instead of gst-launch-0.10